# Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix. Prove that $A^3$ is congruent to $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix.
>
> 1. Prove that $A^3$ is congruent to $A$
> 2. Prove that if $A$ is invertible then $A$ is congruent to $A^{-1}$

I do not know the name of the lemmas and definitions (as they are only written in numbers in my textbook) but I believe those might be useful here:

1. If $A$ is a symmetric real matrix, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=P^TAP$ which is a diagonal matrix.
2. Every symmetric real matrix $A$ is congruent to the diagonal matrix $\text{diag}\{\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{p\text{ }},\underbrace{-1,\ldots,-1}_{n\text{}},0,\ldots,0\}$$=$
   $\left( \begin{matrix}
   I_p & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots & -I_n & \vdots \\
   0 & \cdots & 0\\
   \end{matrix} \right )
   $ $\implies p+n= \rho(A)$
3. A matrix $A$ is orthogonal if $AA^T=A^TA=I$.

So, from given information we get $PP^T=I$ ($P$ is orthogonal matrix) and $$P^{-1}AP=P^tAP=\text{diag}\{\lambda_1 ,\ldots, \lambda_n\}=B.$$

We also have that $$P^{-1}A^3P=P^tA^3P=\text{diag}\{\lambda_1^3,\ldots,\lambda_n^3\}=B^3.$$

How can I get from here to $A^3$ is congruent to $A$?

Thanks for any help and tips hopefully the translations are understandable

Comment: How do you define being congruent?

Comment: You just need to use the definition of congruence and the sign pattern of the eigenvalues (or the signature of the matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(p,n,z)$ be the signature of $A$ (i.e. $p$ positive eigenvalues, $n$ negative eigenvalues, and $z$ zero eigenvalues).

Since the eigenvalues of $A^3$ are those of $A$ cubed, then $A^3$ has the same signature as $A$ and, as a result those matrices are congruent.

Indeed, let $J:=\mathrm{diag}(I_p,-I_n,0_z)$. Therefore, $A$ is congruent to $J$ which means that there exists a nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $J=P^TAP$. Similarly, there exists a nonsingular matrix $Q$ such that $J=Q^TA^3Q$. This implies that $$A^3=Q^{-T}P^TAPQ=\tilde P^TA\tilde P,$$
which shows that the matrices $A$ and $A^3$ are congruent.

If $A$ is invertible, then there exists a nonsingular matrix $R$ such that
$A^{-1}=R^TAR$ and this matrix $R$ is nothing else but $A^{-1}$. It can also be observed that the signature of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the matrix $C$, which is matrix $B$ but with all the $0$s on the diagonal replaced with $1$s. Show that $C^TBC = B^3$.